# Not able to get siblings value from table row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get values from adjacent columns, when a radio button is clicked for that row.
I'm able to do so, but the problem I'm facing, when there are more elements in the radio button column, then i am getting null values(i.e 2nd row is not working). Please help...Code is all follows

```
<table id="dist_list" class="data">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="radio" value="636406" name="distRG" id="radio_7" /></td>
  <td class="selected">Company 1</td>
  <td class="siteId">1234</td>
  <td class="siteName">First Company Name</td>
</tr>

<!-- Not able to get values from this row, since there are more elements in it -->
<tr>
<td>
<span class="jqTransformRadioWrapper"><a rel="distRG" class="jqTransformRadio" href="#"></a>
<input type="radio" value="636406" name="distRG" id="radio_2" />
</span></td>
  <td class="selected">Company 2</td>
  <td class="siteId">2345</td>
  <td class="siteName">Second Company Name</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="radio" value="636406" name="distRG" id="radio_3" /></td>
  <td class="selected">Company 3</td>
  <td class="siteId">3456</td>
  <td class="siteName">Third Company Name</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="radio" value="213584" name="distRG" id="radio_4" /></td>
  <td class="selected">Company 4</td>
  <td class="siteId">4567</td>
  <td class="siteName">Fourth Company Name</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

jQuery script

```
$("input[name=distRG]").click(function() {
    var owner = $(this).parent().siblings('td.selected').text();
    var siteId = $(this).parent().siblings('td.siteId').text();
    var siteName = $(this).parent().siblings('td.siteName').text();
    alert(owner);
    alert(siteId);
    alert(siteName);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the second row is, that `input` is not a child of `td` but of `span`, so `parent()` will give you `span` and not `td`.
 Use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead, which gives you the "closest" ancestor, that matches the selector:

```
var owner = $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.selected').text();
var siteId = $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.siteId').text();
var siteName = $(this).closest('td').siblings('td.siteName').text();
```